# How to start service at device boot in android?

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I am making an app which needs a service running at all times, even when the app is closed, from device boot to device shutdown. Can this be done in android?

Answer (score 10):

1. First you need the permission

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   ```
2. Then create a Broadcast receiver as

   ```
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;

   public class Startup extends BroadcastReceiver {

       public Startup() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // start your service here
           context.startService(new Intent(context, SERVICE.class));
       }

   }
   ```
3. Register this BroadCast Receiver in your manifest as

   ```
   <receiver android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.Startup" >
       <!-- This intent filter receives the boot completed event -->
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

> Note: A service too is not guaranteed to run from device boot to device
>   shut down, as in extreme cases the Android system may kill the service
>   also to gain additional memory.

Comment: It is very important for the app user that the service stay alive always. Is there a way to make sure android doesn't kill the service unless its under extreme load?

Comment: Use an `IntentService` service, which will be restarted if the Service is killed while handling the intent, I haven't come up with other methods yet.

Comment: @twntee dont agree. IntentService is supposed to stop after running once,  so its not going to run all the time.

Comment: @user2103379 In certain case when your IntentService is performing long operation, and system needs to free up memory, it will get killed.

Comment: Try adding android:enabled="true" to the receiver delcalration in manifest.

Comment: `context.startService(new Intent(context, SERVICE.class));` will throw an IllegalStateExeption for Android versions >= Oreo because you can not anymore start a service if app is in background. Check this https://medium.com/@berriz_/service-and-boot-completed-on-android-o-6a389eae50f1